# Show first record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code:

```
@country.assets.each do |asset|                           
  image_tag(asset.image.url(:original), :height=>"300px", :width=>"630px")
end
```

I shows 10 images of the country. I want also show only the first image in my text. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
image_tag(@country.assets.first.image.url(:original), :height=>"300px", :width=>"630px")
```

But note that this is not a great idea to do in the view. It would be better to create an instance variable in the controller:

```
@first_country_asset = @country.first.asset
```

And than create the image tag. Otherwise you start cluttering your views.

Answer (score 0):

```
image_tag(@country.assets.first.image.url(:original), :height=>"300px", :width=>"630px")
```